# Delete data from table that is not exist in other table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables named as **Class** and **Levels**.
I want to delete c_id from Class that does not matche with c_id of Levels. I can do this by a query like here:

```
DELETE FROM class WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM levels WHERE levels.c_id=class.c_id)
```

But I want to do it with a query that work with a link like this:

```
DELETE FROM class WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM levels WHERE levels.c_id=class.c_id) WHERE c_id = '$_GET['del_id']';
```

But I am unable to achieve this. Kindly help me.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what the final additional `WHERE` condition is supposed to be restricting.  Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: do u have any facebook or whatsap. let me send u pictures. snapshots

Comment: LOL...maybe hold off on that.  What do you think that additional `WHERE` term `c_id = '$_GET['del_id']'` is supposed to do?

Comment: dont laugh, i am new to php so m asking.

Comment: No...I'm laughing at the Facebook part...I have never seen this asked here before.  I don't think your question is really a PHP problem, but rather your being able to phrase the logic you want to happen in the query.

Comment: i want to delete the specific and before deletion it check in other table. if i just use first statement it wil delete all c_id that are not second table

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in two steps

```
if (!isset($_GET['del_id'])) {
  die("Invalid ID specified.");
}
$c_id_get = '$_GET['del_id']'


$sql = "DELETE FROM class WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM levels WHERE levels.c_id=class.c_id  && c_id='{$c_id_get}')";
mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might go about doing this via a delete join query between the `class` and `levels` tables.  The criteria then for deleting a record is twofold.  It must match your PHP query parameter and it also must not be present in the `levels` table.  The marker for a record in `class` not being present in `levels` is that the `LEFT JOIN` would have `NULL` join columns in this case (hence the `IS NULL` check you see below).

```
DELETE t1
FROM class t1
LEFT JOIN levels t2
    ON t1.c_id = t2.c_id
WHERE t1.c_id = $_GET['del_id'] AND          -- matches correct class ID
      t2.c_id IS NULL                        -- and not present in 'levels' table
```

**Update:**

From your recent comments, it sounds like what you're really looking for is a cascading delete on the `class` table:

```
ALTER TABLE levels
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_id`
FOREIGN KEY (c_id)
REFERENCES `class` (`c_id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

After adding this constraint, deleting a record from `class` with delete the record *and* will also delete any records in `levels` which point to the record in `class`.

Comment: @shinzu Sorry, it should read `DELETE t1 FROM class t1 ...`  Please try it again

Comment: it says unexpected token t1

Comment: I think your PHP code has some problems.  This query should run without issue in MySQL directly.

Comment: @shinzu Well let's get it working in PHP.  First potential problem I see is the `$_GET` term.  You need to make sure you are using quotes correctly.  Have you done that?

Comment: its done, now would u like to help me, if row exist it says it cant been deleted and if not it says its deleted

Comment: DELETE t1 FROM class t1 LEFT JOIN levels t2 ON t1.c_id = t2.c_id WHERE t1.c_id = '".$_GET['del_class']."'  AND t2.c_id IS NULL

Comment: `if row exist it says it cant been deleted and if not it says its deleted` ... I'm confused now, I thought this was the logic you wanted, at least this is what your question implies.

Comment: Update your question with the actual logic you want to have happen.  Maybe you want to delete from `class` if we _don't_ find a matching record in `levels`?  Or something else?

Comment: no no. i want if row exist in other table it says first delete from there than delete from here, if not exist than it delete

Comment: Oh dear...talk about unclear questions...you just want a cascading delete.  Give me a few minutes, I'll update.

Comment: waiting for ur ans

Comment: @shinzu I gave you an answer hours ago, reload your page.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery for `NOT EXISTS` should return a boolean and the php code should be optimized a litle like this.

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM `class`
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM `levels` 
            WHERE `levels`.`c_id` = ' . (int) $_GET['del_id'] . '
    )
;'
```

You can use `NOT IN` for that too:

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM `class`
    WHERE `class`.`c_id` NOT IN (
        SELECT `levels`.`c_id` FROM `levels` 
            WHERE `levels`.`c_id` = ' . (int) $_GET['del_id'] . '
    )
;'
```

Note: Don't use the request parameters directly in your SQL, for an id simply parse the value to int, for an string or what else you should use mysqli_real_escape_string.